# Writing unit test case in react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I've written a library that makes call to server side APIs, and would be using this library on client side. I've checked mocha-chai but they can test if APIs exist. I want to fake APIs while running test case itself without modifying the data just to make sure that the APIs are being called. Is there some frame work that can help me with that? I do not want to use resources such as [json place holder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) or [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server).

Comment: If you've already decided to use mocha taking a look at sinon.js might be interesting, especially the documentation about stubs: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.1/stubs/

You could stub the function which fetches data from an API to always return a static JSON for example.

Comment: I do not have APIs I actually want something that could give me APIs of my own.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets to share? You're writing that you've written a library which makes calls to server side APIs but in your tests you don't want to actually do the API calls to the server (this makes sense), but instead determine the response of the API call yourself based on which test you're running. Is that correct?

Comment: I do not intend to determine the response of the API only thing I want to do is check if multiple types of responses with different http status and reponse types with different headers to make sure the code does not break. So that someone using the function could get proper response from my side if the input params to functions of my library are invalid, for example method type of an API.

Comment: To me this sounds like you want to test if the the *request* to the API endpoint is correct, rather than checking the *response* you receive from the API is correct.

On your client, you'll want to test if the client communicates with the API in the correct manner, your client has no control over the API behavior.

So whenever a user inputs `x` and `y` in your program, you'll be asserting if the API was called with `x` and `y` correctly. The tests for the API itself should be made on the server (if you have control over it)

Comment: Yes exactly I want to check  if the client communicates with the API in the correct manner, sorry for not being able to explain, that's what I meant how do you suggest that can be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156669/discussion-between-niekert-and-tgw).